# How to check for a word in a text file line by line and when you found print the whole line

Tags: c

Check for a word in a text file line by line and when you found it,print the whole line,the program receives as command line argumets the text file and the word you are searching for.
Here is what I've tried to do so far,but I have segmentation fault and I don't really know what I'm supposed to do.

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    FILE *file;
    if(argc!=3)
    {
        printf("error 1");
        exit(1);
    }
    if((file=fopen(argv[1],"r"))==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error");
        exit(1);
    }
    char line[100];
    char *p;
    while(!feof(file))
    {
        fgets(line,sizeof(line),file);
        p=strtok(line," ");
        while(strcmp(p,argv[2])!=0)
            p=strtok(NULL," ");
        if(strcmp(p,argv[2])==0)
        {
            printf("%s",line);
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: By the way, your usage of `while(!feof(file))` looks [wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong).

Comment: make a copy of the line string before using `strtok`, which is destructive. Then you have the original line to report.

Comment: Welcome to SO. First step would be to run your program in a debugger. Step through your code and watch if the variables contain expected values. You can also just run it in debugger and when the segfault happens inspect where it happened and what data was used.

Comment: `while(strcmp(p,argv[2])!=0)` you know that `strtok` might return `NULL`, do you?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing `strcmp(p,argv[2])` without checking `p` is `NULL`. You should check that.

Also your usage of `while(!feof(file))` is [wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong). You should check if readings succeeded before using what are "read".

Fixed code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    FILE *file;
    if(argc!=3)
    {
        printf("error 1");
        exit(1);
    }
    if((file=fopen(argv[1],"r"))==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error");
        exit(1);
    }
    char line[100];
    char *p;
    while(fgets(line,sizeof(line),file)) /* check if reading succeeded */
    {
        p=strtok(line," ");
        while(p!=NULL && strcmp(p,argv[2])!=0) /* check if p is not NULL */
        {
            p=strtok(NULL," ");
        }
        if(p!=NULL && strcmp(p,argv[2])==0) /* check if p is not NULL */
        {
            printf("%s",line);
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would make a copy of the input and then "when you found print the whole line".

Comment: @Alexx2901 [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68545124/edit) and show an example of input annd expected vs. actual output.

Comment: It's ok.I have managed to solve it.Thank u.